# Components of Poisson Distribution mean

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution

Suppose that we have a game between Team A and Team B. Team A has a 75% probability of winning and Team B has a 25% probability of winning. Draw cannot occur. I also know, that there is calculated average of points scored in this game and it is 3.5. This average consists of average of points scored by Team A and average of points scored by Team B. How can I calculate those averages per team?

Comment: I know the result - Team A: 2.258, Team B: 1.242, but I can't discover the way to calculate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the score of A and $Y$ the score of B. Define $E[X] = a, E[Y] = b$.
We know that
$$
P(X > Y) = P(X - Y > 0) = 0.75
$$
and that
$E[X + Y] = a + b = 3.5$ so, $b = a - 3.5$. Define $Z = X - Y$, then
$$
P(X > Y) = P(Z > 0) = 1 - P(Z \le -1)
$$
If $X$ and $Y$ were poission the probability of the difference being zero would be $p_0 = e^{-(a + b)}  I_{0}(2\sqrt{ab})$ where $I$ is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1.

Since draws are not allowed, we have to truncate the distribution so:
$P(Z \le -1) = \frac{F(-1)}{1-p_0}$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function for the non-truncated distribution given by:
$F(-1; a, b) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{-1} e^{-(a + b)}  \big(\frac{a}{b}\big)^{k/2}I_{k}(2\sqrt{ab})$.

In your case,
$$0.75 = 1 - \frac{F(-1; a, 3.5 - a)}{1-p_0}.$$
Solving this gives $a = 2.2577$ and $b =  1.2423$ which agrees with your suggested answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the answer. I really appreciate it. Would you be that kind and give me some hints about the best way of solving this equation? To be honest - I'm a software developer who is trying to adapt this solution to my software and I have a lack in knowledge of math

Comment: Still trying to solve this step by step either on the WolframAlpha or on the WolframCloud and can't manage how to do it properly. Another question - would that formula work for different probabilities and averages?

Comment: I've managed to calculate this numericaly in R language. I have limited $-\infty$ to the -200 because for my input it is enough. Thank you one more time @Hunaphu

Comment: Of course - ocera002x@gmail.com